# Java socket BufferedReader read not reading

Tags: java, sockets

Im trying to make a client/server socket connection via BufferedReader and Buffered Writer, but reader not reading anything it is just hanged, where client send and flush properly.
Server does not throw any exception as if client not sending anything to server.

My head is going go explode...

Im using same for both client and server:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

Here is the code of server:

```
//inside of try catch
while(true){
          while(!in.ready())// just to debug
            System.out.println("READY: " + in.ready()); //just to debug
          System.out.println("READY: OK"); //just to debug
            msg = receive().toString(); //hangs here...
            System.out.println("KEYIS: " + msg);
           ///some stuff to do ....

public StringBuilder receive() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    int tmp;
    while(true){
        tmp = in.read();
        if(tmp == 0)
            break;
        else if(tmp == -1)
            throw new IOException();
        str.append((char)tmp);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Client code: not hanging here

```
 //inside of try catch
         send(KEY); //sended properly, no exception
         while(true){
             send(KEY); // sended properly, no exception
             System.out.println("sent");
             //System.out.println(receive().toString());
         }

public void send(String str) throws IOException{
    out.write(str + "\n"); //
    //out.newLine(); //tried too, not helped
    out.flush(); //push message to server
}
```

Comment: Why do you use BufferedReader? Try to remove it, that should help.

Comment: As per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307026/7758804) below by the poster, this was caused by a typo and is not reproducible. I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well server waits for `if(tmp == 0)` which is `0` is a nil, and the client never sends it.
I think You are waiting about `\n` which it's not 0, it's 10(line feed).
Just wondered why don't you use `DataOutputStream#writeUTF()` and `DataInputStream#readUTF()`?

Comment: \0 used to determine the end of data, -1 means that there was an error in connection.

Comment: readUTF can not be resolved by lua program, that will connect to server too

Comment: @Bob No, an *`IOException`* means that there was an error in the connection. -1 means that the peer has *closed* the connection. No error.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing lines but you have a pretty pointless and elaborate and very buggy input method which doesn't actually read lines, and which throws the wrong exception at end of stream.

Try `BufferedReader.readLine()`, not forgetting to test for null.

Comment: I have to pass the data that may contain \n \r characters, so cant use readLine

Comment: So use `BufferedInputStream.read()` then, and don't use `String` as a container for binary data.

Answer (score 1):

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i;
    while ((i = bi.read()) != -1) {
        char c = (char) i;
        sb.append(c);
        
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem... So stupid mistake... I just forgot to add a \0 to determine the end of message, so recieve method was waiting as if more data coming...